# Dataweave Payload Transformation - NetSuite SOAP

Tags: soap, mule, netsuite, dataweave, mule4

I have JSON payload which I need to transform and make a call to NetSuite.
Payload:

```
 [{
    "Netsuite Sales Order Id": "13738407",
    "Project Number": "CSPRJ0010592",
    "Project Sys Id": "0863d7141b9861548e835244604btest1",
   "Netsuite Sales Order Line Id": "1",
    "Project Task Number": "CSPRJTASK0322101",
    "Project Task Sys Id": "0f345f141b9861548e8352446TASK1",
    "Update Flag": false
    },
    {
    "Netsuite Sales Order Id":"13738407",
    "Project Number": "CSPRJ0010593",
    "Project Sys Id": "0863d7141b9861548e835244604btest2",
    "Netsuite Sales Order Line Id": "3",
    "Project Task Number": "CSPRJTASK0322102",
    "Project Task Sys Id": "0f345f141b9861548e835244604TASK4",
    "Update Flag": false
    }]
```

I need to use NetSuite Sales order ID and update the sale order with this payload on Body level field.

Code I used but didn't work:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml
ns ns0 urn:messages_2021_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com
ns ns01 urn:relationships_2021_1.lists.webservices.netsuite.com
ns ns02 urn:core_2021_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com
ns ns03 urn:sales_2021_1.transactions.webservices.netsuite.com
ns xsi http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance
---
{
    ns0#update: {
        (payload map((item,index) ->
            ns0#record @(internalId: item."Netsuite Sales Order Id", "xmlns:ns03": ns03, xsi#"type": "ns03:SalesOrder"): {
            ns03#customFieldList: {
                StringCustomFieldRef__custbody_eb_mulesoft_data: {
                    ns02#value: { NetsuiteSalesOrderLineId: item."Netsuite Sales Order Line Id",
                        ProjectSysId: item."Project Sys Id",
                    ProjectNumber: item."Project Number",
                    ProjectTaskNumber: item."Project Task Number",
                    ProjectTaskSysId: item."Project Task Sys Id"
                    
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }
        ))
    }
}
```

I need to send whole payload to NetSuite sales order body level field as JSON.
Field : custbody_eb_mulesoft_data

Please help.

Output i receive for above code which is the error:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ns0:update xmlns:ns0="urn:messages_2021_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
  <ns0:record internalId="13738407" xmlns:ns03="urn:sales_2021_1.transactions.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns03:SalesOrder">
    <ns03:customFieldList xmlns:ns03="urn:sales_2021_1.transactions.webservices.netsuite.com">
      <StringCustomFieldRef__custbody_eb_mulesoft_data>
        <ns02:value xmlns:ns02="urn:core_2021_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
          <NetsuiteSalesOrderLineId>1</NetsuiteSalesOrderLineId>
          <ProjectSysId>0863d7141b9861548e835244604btest1</ProjectSysId>
          <ProjectNumber>CSPRJ0010592</ProjectNumber>
          <ProjectTaskNumber>CSPRJTASK0322101</ProjectTaskNumber>
          <ProjectTaskSysId>0f345f141b9861548e8352446TASK1</ProjectTaskSysId>
        </ns02:value>
      </StringCustomFieldRef__custbody_eb_mulesoft_data>
    </ns03:customFieldList>
  </ns0:record>
  <ns0:record internalId="13738407" xmlns:ns03="urn:sales_2021_1.transactions.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns03:SalesOrder">
    <ns03:customFieldList xmlns:ns03="urn:sales_2021_1.transactions.webservices.netsuite.com">
      <StringCustomFieldRef__custbody_eb_mulesoft_data>
        <ns02:value xmlns:ns02="urn:core_2021_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
          <NetsuiteSalesOrderLineId>3</NetsuiteSalesOrderLineId>
          <ProjectSysId>0863d7141b9861548e835244604btest2</ProjectSysId>
          <ProjectNumber>CSPRJ0010593</ProjectNumber>
          <ProjectTaskNumber>CSPRJTASK0322102</ProjectTaskNumber>
          <ProjectTaskSysId>0f345f141b9861548e835244604TASK4</ProjectTaskSysId>
        </ns02:value>
      </StringCustomFieldRef__custbody_eb_mulesoft_data>
    </ns03:customFieldList>
  </ns0:record>
</ns0:update>
```

Notice i have 2 NS records but it should only be 1 record being updated.

Expected output or is there a way i can push the same payload referenced on top?:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ns0:update xmlns:ns0="urn:messages_2021_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
  <ns0:record internalId="13738407" xmlns:ns03="urn:sales_2021_1.transactions.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns03:SalesOrder">
    <ns03:customFieldList xmlns:ns03="urn:sales_2021_1.transactions.webservices.netsuite.com">
      <StringCustomFieldRef__custbody_eb_mulesoft_data>
        <ns02:value xmlns:ns02="urn:core_2021_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
          <NetsuiteSalesOrderLineId>1</NetsuiteSalesOrderLineId>
          <ProjectSysId>0863d7141b9861548e835244604btest1</ProjectSysId>
          <ProjectNumber>CSPRJ0010592</ProjectNumber>
          <ProjectTaskNumber>CSPRJTASK0322101</ProjectTaskNumber>
          <ProjectTaskSysId>0f345f141b9861548e8352446TASK1</ProjectTaskSysId>
          <NetsuiteSalesOrderLineId>3</NetsuiteSalesOrderLineId>
          <ProjectSysId>0863d7141b9861548e835244604btest2</ProjectSysId>
          <ProjectNumber>CSPRJ0010593</ProjectNumber>
          <ProjectTaskNumber>CSPRJTASK0322102</ProjectTaskNumber>
          <ProjectTaskSysId>0f345f141b9861548e835244604TASK4</ProjectTaskSysId>
        </ns02:value>
      </StringCustomFieldRef__custbody_eb_mulesoft_data>
    </ns03:customFieldList>
  </ns0:record>
</ns0:update>
```

Comment: "didn't work" is not helpful. Please clarify the question and what exactly is the error. Is the input payload an array or an object with a `Payload` key? What is the the expected XML output? what is the actual output? What errors do you see, or what issues are happening? Be specific. Edit your question to improve it. Reading the 
[How to Ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) pages will be help to improve your question and increase the chances for an answer.

Comment: Ok, you shared the actual output, what is your expected output?

Comment: @aled See the post. It can be the main payload on top or i added a mockup expected payload output.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are sure that multiple repeated element with the same name are ok, move the map() under `ns02#value` and make it an object (`{...}`) so the key-values inside the parenthesis are added inside.
I'm assuming the input array has always at least one item, so we can take the `internalId` from the first item directly.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/xml
ns ns0 urn:messages_2021_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com
ns ns01 urn:relationships_2021_1.lists.webservices.netsuite.com
ns ns02 urn:core_2021_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com
ns ns03 urn:sales_2021_1.transactions.webservices.netsuite.com
ns xsi http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance
---
{
    ns0#update: {
        ns0#record @(internalId: payload[0]."Netsuite Sales Order Id", "xmlns:ns03": ns03, xsi#"type": "ns03:SalesOrder"): {
        ns03#customFieldList: {
            StringCustomFieldRef__custbody_eb_mulesoft_data: 
                ns02#value: {
                    (payload map((item,index) -> {
                        NetsuiteSalesOrderLineId: item."Netsuite Sales Order Line Id",
                        ProjectSysId: item."Project Sys Id",
                        ProjectNumber: item."Project Number",
                        ProjectTaskNumber: item."Project Task Number",
                        ProjectTaskSysId: item."Project Task Sys Id"             
                    }))
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Output:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ns0:update xmlns:ns0="urn:messages_2021_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
  <ns0:record internalId="15922713" xmlns:ns03="urn:sales_2021_1.transactions.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns03:SalesOrder">
    <ns03:customFieldList xmlns:ns03="urn:sales_2021_1.transactions.webservices.netsuite.com">
      <StringCustomFieldRef__custbody_eb_mulesoft_data>
        <ns02:value xmlns:ns02="urn:core_2021_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
          <NetsuiteSalesOrderLineId>1</NetsuiteSalesOrderLineId>
          <ProjectSysId>54d948a11b680690fbe1535b234bcb26</ProjectSysId>
          <ProjectNumber>CSPRJ0018639</ProjectNumber>
          <ProjectTaskNumber>CSPRJTASK0858566</ProjectTaskNumber>
          <ProjectTaskSysId>85d948a11b680690fbe1535b234bcb50</ProjectTaskSysId>
          <NetsuiteSalesOrderLineId>3</NetsuiteSalesOrderLineId>
          <ProjectSysId>54d948a11b680690fbe1535b234bcb26</ProjectSysId>
          <ProjectNumber>CSPRJ0018639</ProjectNumber>
          <ProjectTaskNumber>CSPRJTASK0858567</ProjectTaskNumber>
          <ProjectTaskSysId>4ad9c4ad1b280290751bcaab234bcb8a</ProjectTaskSysId>
        </ns02:value>
      </StringCustomFieldRef__custbody_eb_mulesoft_data>
    </ns03:customFieldList>
  </ns0:record>
</ns0:update>
```

If you remove the curly braces in `ns02#value` the script will generate one `ns02#value` per item in the input array.

Answer (score -1):

If your object looks like this:

```
{
  "Payload": [
    {
      "Netsuite Sales Order Id": "15922713",
      "Project Number": "CSPRJ0018639",
      "Project Sys Id": "54d948a11b680690fbe1535b234bcb26",
      "Netsuite Sales Order Line Id": "1",
      "Project Task Number": "CSPRJTASK0858566",
      "Project Task Sys Id": "85d948a11b680690fbe1535b234bcb50"
    },
    {
      "Netsuite Sales Order Id": "15922713",
      "Project Number": "CSPRJ0018639",
      "Project Sys Id": "54d948a11b680690fbe1535b234bcb26",
      "Netsuite Sales Order Line Id": "3",
      "Project Task Number": "CSPRJTASK0858567",
      "Project Task Sys Id": "4ad9c4ad1b280290751bcaab234bcb8a"
    }
  ]
}
```

then your transformation should look like this:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml
ns ns0 urn:messages_2021_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com
ns ns01 urn:relationships_2021_1.lists.webservices.netsuite.com
ns ns02 urn:core_2021_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com
ns ns03 urn:sales_2021_1.transactions.webservices.netsuite.com
ns xsi http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance
---
{
    ns0#update: {
        (payload.Payload map ((item,index) ->
            ns0#record @(internalId: item."Netsuite Sales Order Id", "xmlns:ns03": ns03, xsi#"type": "ns03:SalesOrder"): {
            ns03#customFieldList: {
                StringCustomFieldRef__custbody_eb_mulesoft_data: {
                    ns02#value: { NetsuiteSalesOrderLineId: item."Netsuite Sales Order Line Id",
                        ProjectSysId: item."Project Sys Id",
                    ProjectNumber: item."Project Number",
                    ProjectTaskNumber: item."Project Task Number",
                    ProjectTaskSysId: item."Project Task Sys Id"
                    
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }
        ))
    }
}
```

Notice the "payload.Payload"

Comment: Hi, I fixed the post. It was the debug i copied. Sorry about that.